Converting world space transform to pose space for a bone
I have an animation (list of keyframes) that is relative to world space (i.e. the translation/rotation/scale of each bone at each keyframe is assumed to happen in the worlds coordinate system, which for blender is x right, y forward, z up) but animations in blender happen in pose space, so i need to convert each of these to pose space
To simplify this problem, assume that i have an armature with just three connected bones

Bone 1 (root)
Bone 2 (child of Bone 1)
Bone 3 (child of Bone 2)

Now, assume that i have defined one keyframe, which transforms Bone 2 and Bone 3
It rotates bone 2 by any arbitrary rotation, e.g. (45, 75, 30) in euler angles and it also rotates bone 3 by any arbitrary rotation, e.g. (90, 0, 45)
Both of these rotations are in world space, so if i add these transforms to the keyframe as is, then most likely it will not work unless the bones local axes are aligned with the world, if they are not then this will not look right
So, what needs to happen is that the rotations need to be converted from the worlds coordinate system to the bones coordinate system (defined by its local axes) and it also needs to take into account how the bone might've been influenced by the parent bone(s), e.g. in this case both Bone 2 and Bone 3 has a rotation applied, so first Bone 2 applies its rotation, then Bone 3 will inherit the rotation of Bone 2 and finally it will apply its own rotation, however when Bone 3 inherited the rotation of Bone 2, its local axes changed and the conversion needs to take that into account
How can i implement this in blenders Python API?
I am also fine with a mathematical explanation of how to do this, as I'll probably be able to convert it to code
